# Angular2- few questions related to data saving in a static web page

Tags: javascript, json, angular

Im coding a static page app using Angular, which shows various Instagram and Twitter posts of the company, and shows the details of the members. I have few questions regarding this, and would like any help.
Firstly, I have about 100+ contacts to display on the first page. Should I create a Json by myself and retrieve it from the service, or should I create a backend and save it there ? I do not have any backend as of now.
Other thing, I was able to retrieve Instagram Json with media content using their API, the doubt im facing is, once I have the call done, will the Json change automatically when the user adds/edits their posts? Or will the Json be the same as I first called it with? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I create a Json by myself and retrieve it from the service, or should I create a backend and save it there ?

Are you revealing credentials or other sensitive information in the client? That would be one reason to have a backend apart from Instagram or Twitter. Do you envision exhausting API rate limits of Instagram or Twitter APIs? That would be another reason; you could cache results in your backend to reduce external API traffic. Do you need to process (reduce? translate?) the data before it gets to the client, or are you satisfied with performing any processing on the client (e.g. is it fast enough)?

TL;DR: It depends a lot on your particular requirements.

If you do want a backend, the recommendation in the answer from @praneeth-reddy to use [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) is excellent. If you only need processing/transformation but no caching or separate storage, then [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) may also be worth considering. If you need more control (build vs. buy), you could write your own backend.

> ...will the Json change automatically when the user adds/edits their posts? Or will the Json be the same as I first called it with?

Angular can help you update content automatically if the client side data (think browser JavaScript memory) changes via its automatic [change detection](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html#!#sts=Change%20Detection) functionality, but you would have to provide your own logic (e.g. in Angular [services](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html) perhaps leveraging RxJS) to update the client side data based on data from the APIs. You could poll to update periodically, or for better performance listen for changes using an asynchronous event/push mechanism such as websockets or streams.

Comment: Sure, thanks for the response. 
I am not bringing any sensitive data, its public info that I need to display to any user. Do I really need a backend for this? Im not storing any data on the site, its like a public page they want to see. Im doubting as to why Im using Angular except the webapp part, but I just want to gain more knowledge in it so im going for that.

Answer (score 0):

For your case, as you have fewer data using **Firebase** is the best approach. If you write a backend and maintaining it would cost you more. You can use Firebase service URL to retire those records. In future, if you want to add more data it would be easy.My suggestion is **Firebase**.